# Send Data From Firestore To Shared Preferences Kotlin in Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, sharedpreferences

I'm building an app and I have Firestore server, when specific button pressed I wanted to get data from firebase and save it to the Shared Preference but it's no seem to work.

```
db.collection("Groups1").document("${codeEntered}").get().addOnSuccessListener {doc ->
                    if(doc.exists()){
                        val groups = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("groupCodes", HashSet<String>())
                        if(groups?.contains(codeEntered)!!){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You're Already in ${codeEntered}.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You Enter ${codeEntered} Group!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            groups?.plusAssign(codeEntered)
                            editSharedPreferences.putStringSet("groupCodes", groups)
                            val data = doc.data.hashCode()
                            //Add Set The Group In FireStore
                            db.collection("Groups1").document(codeEntered).get().addOnSuccessListener {doc ->
                                var data = doc.getData() as MutableMap<String, Any>
                                data["${sharedPreferences.getInt("mainId", 0)}"] = 0
                                db.collection("Groups1").document(codeEntered).set(data)
                                editSharedPreferences.apply()
                            }
                            getData(object : MyCallback {
                                override fun onCallback(value: HashMap<String, Int>) {
                                    listView.adapter = adapterListView(MainActivity.appContext, value, sizeOfListMain, sharedPreferences.getInt("mainColor", 0)) }
                            })
                            var codeGroup = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("groupCodes", HashSet<String>()) as HashSet<String>

                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "${codeEntered} is Not Exists.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Looks like you missed [Apply Changes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor#apply())

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: The Data don't saved to the shared Perf @AlexMamo

Comment: I Have .apply() inside the db @rahat